# How to create a new relational realmResults?

Tags: android, database, realm

I created a realm object(*VolleyballPlayer*) according to other realm objects. **Female** object includes all **Volleyball** objects but **Male** object has some **Volleyball** objects.

I want to create **VolleyballPlayer** object that group **Female** and **Male** objects for gender. But I couldn't find how to do it according to RealmResults.

My realm objects:

```
public class Volleyball extends RealmObject {
    private int round;
    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}

//...All  females play volleyball.
public class Female extends RealmObject {
    private Volleyball volleyball;
    private int clasp;
    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}

public class Male extends RealmObject {
    private Volleyball volleyball;
    private int belt;
    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}
```

New object:

```
public class VolleyballPlayer extends RealmObject {
    private Volleyball volleyball;
    private String gender;

    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}
```

I have allFemale and allMale realmResults but I haven't take allPlayer realmResults.

```
RealmResults<Female> allFemales = mRealm.where(Female.class).findAll();
RealmResults<Male> allMales = mRealm.where(Male.class).findAll();
```

All female students play volleyball and how can I extract male players from through all the players(in females) who play volleyball?
Is there a way in the realm that I write below code:

```
 public void setAllVolleyballPlayers(Realm mRealm) {
        Realm mRealm = getRealm();

        mRealm.beginTransaction();
        addAllMalePlayers(mRealm);
        addAllFemalePlayers(mRealm);
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
    }

    private void addAllMalePlayers(Realm mRealm) {
        RealmResults<Male> allMalePlayers = new MalePlayersQueries().getAllMales(mRealm);

        mRealm.beginTransaction();

        if (allMalePlayers != null && allMalePlayers.size() > 0) {

           VolleyballPlayer volleyballPlayer = mRealm.createObject(VolleyballPlayer.class);
           volleyballPlayer.setGender(getString(R.string.male));

           for (Male male : allMales) {
            
           VolleyballPlayer volleyballPlayer = 
           mRealm.createObject(VolleyballPlayer.class);
           volleyballPlayer.setVolleyball(male.getVolleyball());
           }
        }
    }

   private void addAllFemalePlayers(Realm mRealm) {
           RealmResults<Female> allFemales = new FemaleQueries().getAllPlayers(mRealm);

           VolleyballPlayer volleyballPlayer = mRealm.createObject(VolleyballPlayer.class);
           volleyballPlayer.setGender(getString(R.string.female));

           ////// All female students play volleyball and how can I extract male players from all the players(in females) who play this volleyball and get females
}
```

And I want to show at the end of table:

```
  **Volleyball Players**
    
  **Female**
    Emma
    Olivia
    Sophia

  **Male**
    John
    Jame
```

Comment: Volleyball has no fields. Why does it exist, then? What is the difference between `Male`/`Female`, and `Student`? Are all Male/Females also Students?

Comment: Yes all male and females are student.

Comment: Is there a difference between a `sequenceNumber` and a `setNumber`? Or are they the same thing, except in two different classes? What exactly does it mean to have a `Volleyball` set in Female/Male? It means they have played 1 specific game of Volleyball? What about more games of Volleyball?

Comment: There is no logic between these fields -> sequence and setNumber. You can see my edited answer

Comment: I'm asking primarily to know if `sequence` is a male-specific thing, and `set` is a female-specific thing. And if that means Males **cannot** have `sequence`s.

Comment: Set or sequence number only number and It does not matter. You don't care these. Male-specific object is belt and female-specific object is clasp anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd leverage the power of "single-table-inheritance using discriminator field" for this.

```
public class Volleyball extends RealmObject {
    private int round;

    @LinkingObjects("volleyball")
    private final RealmResults<VolleyBallPlayer> playedBy = null;
    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}

public class VolleyBallPlayer extends RealmObject {
    private Volleyball volleyball;
    @Index
    private String gender;
    private int femaleClasp; // 0, or with Integer `null` if male
    private int maleBelt; // 0, or with Integer `null` if female
    // ... Generated getters and setters ...
}
```

Now you can do

```
RealmResults<VolleyBallPlayer> femalePlayers = realm.where(VolleyBallPlayer.class)
     .equalTo("gender", Gender.FEMALE.name()).findAll();
RealmResults<VolleyBallPlayer> malePlayers = realm.where(VolleyBallPlayer.class)
     .equalTo("gender", Gender.MALE.name()).findAll();
```

And even

```
RealmResults<Volleyball> maleVolleyballs = realm.where(Volleyball.class)
     .equalTo("playedBy.gender", Gender.MALE.name()).findAll();
```

Comment: very thanks but actually my question is how to create VolleyballPlayer realmresults.

Comment: As I said, I'd merge Male and Female together. That would make your queries trivial.

Comment: my femalePlayers,malePlayers and maleVolleyballs are empty. I can't find that how can I fill it?

Comment: All female students play volleyball and how can I extract male players from through all the players(in females) who play volleyball?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing anymore.

Comment: I just think you never redefined `VolleyballPlayer` like I said you should. I'd just remove `Male` and `Female` classes completely.